# Mobile friendly template

Tags: html, css, templates, mobile

I'm trying to create a mobile friendly website but I can't seem to get my base template right.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvQqb/

The template needs to be fullscreen, but not all the text needs to be small like my HTC Sensation (Cellphone) displays.
So it needs to have a width of 100% but it does not have to be seen like it is zoomed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mobile browser will often assume, by default, that it's loading a page that was designed for a large screen, and therefore will make an assumption of size and then just zoom the entire document down.

To tell the mobile browser you want to target it's own screen size, you need to add the viewport meta tag information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start is [html5 Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile).

> Why it is awesome
>
> - Cross-platform compatible (Android, iOS, Blackberry, Symbian)
> - CSS class to target IE Mobile 7
> - Home screen icon (Android, iOS, Symbian)
> - Cross browser viewport optimization for Opera Mobile, Android, iOS, IE, Nokia, Blackberry.
> - Optimized viewport scaling (Opera Mobile, Android, iOS, Mobile IE, Blackberry)
> - Option to enable iOS start-screen in full screen mode
> - Better font rendering on IE Mobile
> - Adaptable markup and CSS skeleton
> - CSS stylesheet for low-end devices
> - Mobile sitemap
> - Mobile MIME type support
> - Build tool for mobile
> - Fix iPhone reflow scale up bug